# С # паттерн Adapter и MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования, adapter

```
public class ViewModelCreatContactInPhone 
{
    DataBaseAdapter DBA = new Adapter();
    public ContactBaseFactory PFMB { get; set; }
    public DataBaseAdapter exp { get; set; }

    public ViewModelCreatContactInPhone() 
    {
        exp = new Adapter();
        PFMB = exp.PFMB;
    }

    public void AddContactInPhone() 
    {
        try
        {     
            DBA.Add();
        } 
        catch (Exception) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при добовлении записи в базе данных.");
        }
    }
}

public abstract class DataBaseAdapter 
{
    public ContactBaseFactory PFMB { get; set; }
    public abstract  void Add();
}

public class Adapter : DataBaseAdapter 
{
    ContactSimDB CSB = new ContactSimDB();
    ConcreteCreatorContact CCC = new ConcreteCreatorContact();
    public Adapter() 
    {
        PFMB = CCC.FactoryMethod();         
    }

    public override void Add() 
    {
        CSB.SpecificAdd(PFMB);
    }
}
```

Есть метод `SpecificAdd(){}`, который должен выполняться. Он не выполняется, потому что мое окно с `dataContext`-ом привязано к `ViewModelCreatContactInPhone`, и тут я создаю `public ContactBaseFactory PFMB { get; set; }`, так же это я создаю в `DataBaseAdapter`-е, а он уже не привязан с `dataContext`-ом.

Мне надо `PFMB` из `ViewModel`-и приревновать с `PFMB` из `DataBaseAdapter` в конструкторе написано `ViewModel`-и написано как я пробовал но почему то не получается. Как связать эти две `PFMB`?

**Обновление**

у меня есть `ContactBaseFactory PFMB { get; set; }` в `ViewModelCreatContactInPhone`, которое видно в окне WPF, то есть я в биндинге, например, texBox-а пишу

```
"{Binding Path=PFMB.PhoneNumber_Phone }"
```

Еще есть `ContactBaseFactory PFMB { get; set; }` в `DataBaseAdapter`, которого окно не видит, потому что `dataCantext` привязано к `ViewModelCreatContactInPhone`. мне надо `ContactBaseFactory PFMB { get; set; }`-ы  как-нибудь связать из обоих классов, чтобы *Binding* сработало.

Comment: Может более корректно сформулируете вопрос? Если честно, из фразы "Мне надо PFMB из ViewModel-и приревновать с PFMB из DataBaseAdapter в конструкторе написано ViewModel-и написано как я пробовал но почему то не получается. " мало, что понятно.